# Type does not have null as a proper value

Tags: f#

For the sample program:

```
type public MyClass(reasonForLiving:string) =
    member x.ReasonForLiving with get() = reasonForLiving

let classFactory () = MyClass("up to you")
let live () =
    let instance = classFactory()
    if instance = null then raise(System.Exception("null is not living... that's why OO languages die from bugs"))
    instance
```

I get the error "The type 'MyClass' does not have null as a proper value" when I go to use this class as a return value of implicitly typed functions and compare it to *null* (b/c of compatibility requirements with C# dependency injection I cannot rely on F# option types).

I can easily fix this by changing the null check to:

```
if instance :> obj = null then
```

However, I know ("feel") this is completely "wrong". Especially when I consider how MyClass is a reference type that shouldn't need to be boxed (speaking from a C# background).

I've read about "F# Value Restriction" and how it impacts type inference, but I can't seem to gleam how it applies to this scenario.

**Q: Is there another way to do this?**

*Aside #1:* I found a simpler method of getting the error...

```
type public MyClass(reasonForLiving:string) =
    member x.ReasonForLiving with get() = reasonForLiving
let nullMyClass : MyClass = null
```

*Aside #2:* I did try System.Nullable without thinking... MyClass is a reference type and not a value type (struct) which Nullable<_> requires. So, just reassures me that I REALLY am dealing with a reference type and leaves me wondering why an object cast suddenly makes this work.

**Update:** For anyone interested, I used this as one solution for Common Service Locator with the three functions below. Each service requested must support *null*, so if the service class is defined in F#, you need to add the `[<AllowNullLiteral>]`:

```
let private getServiceLocator () =
    try Some(Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current)
    with | _ -> None

let private getService serviceFactory =
    let serviceLocator = getServiceLocator()
    let service = match serviceLocator with 
                  | None -> serviceFactory()
                  | _ -> 
                    match serviceLocator.Value.GetInstance<'a>() with
                    | null -> serviceFactory()
                    | svc -> svc
    match service with
    | null -> None
    | _ -> Some(service)

let private getRequiredService serviceFactory =
    let service = getService serviceFactory
    match service with
    | None -> raise(MissingServiceException(""))
    | _ -> service.Value
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the [`[<AllowNullLiteral>]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353608.aspx) attribute:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type public MyClass(reasonForLiving:string) =
    member x.ReasonForLiving with get() = reasonForLiving
```

By default, F# types do not allow null (thank heavens!). This attribute is useful for interop with other .NET languages and allows assignment/comparison with null.

Comment: Doh! After seeing this, I recognized it from the third sentence on MSDN "Null Values (F#)": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233197(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just to add - it is more idiomatic to use `Option 't` if you do not do interop

Comment: John - Yes, I mentioned not being able to use Option.
So, pretty much every class exposed to C# would need `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` to work as a C# dev would expect... :(

Comment: @Eric : Classes, records, and DUs can be set to null from C# regardless of the presence (or lack thereof) of `AllowNullLiteral` – after all, they are all still reference types under the hood. The attribute only allows one to set something to null _from F#_.

Answer (score 23):

The problem with the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute is that in addition to allowing you to compare your objects to null, it also makes it possible to *set* your objects *to* null.

Assuming that this is not desirable for your use-case, there is an easy alternative with unobservable performance impact:

```
let inline isNull (x:^T when ^T : not struct) = obj.ReferenceEquals (x, null)
```

Then rather than doing `if instance = null then`, do `if isNull instance then` instead.

This will work for any reference type (including records and DUs), but does not introduce the possibility of setting objects of your F# types to null from F# – the best of both worlds.

Comment: I used this approach on a large-ish project once, but ended up regretting it. If a type can be null (either in F# or due to interop) it's best that it's explicit. One example is pattern matching. What's better, defining a null-checking active pattern or `match value with null -> ...`? In the end, such workarounds felt hacky. For interop, just add `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` to your types and embrace null.

Comment: @Daniel : I get the impression that the OP simply wants to use F# types from C#, so I don't know how much true interop is going on...

Comment: The above isNull definition produced the syntax error: ``Explicit type parameters may only be used on module or member bindings``

I tried this instead: ``let isNull (x:obj) = obj.ReferenceEquals (x, Unchecked.defaultof<_>)``

Of course, it will accept any value since the parameter binding automatically up-cast it to object (with the consequential box effort). So the compiler warning for non-reference value is lost.

Comment: @George : Given that this is a general-purpose utility function, I had assumed it would be defined at module-scope, at which point there is no syntax error. I've updated the answer with syntax that will work at module scope or in function scope, thanks for letting me know about the issue. :-]